# Blueprism-like spying and bot development

Tags: c#, python, windows, blueprism, rpa

Blueprism gives the possibility to spy elements (like buttons and textboxes) in both web-browsers and windows applications. How can I spy (windows-based only) applications using Python, R, Java, C++, C# or other, anything but not Blueprism, preferrably opensource.

1. For web-browsers, I know how to do this, without being an expert. Using Python or R, for example, I can use Selenium or RSelenium, to spy elements of a website using different ways such as CSS selector, xpath, ID, Class Name, Tag, Text etc.
2. But for Applications, I have no clue. BluePrism has mainly two different App spying modes which are WIN32 and Active Accessibility. How can I do this type of spying and interacting with an application outside of Blueprism, preferrably using an opensource language?

(only interested in windows-based apps for now)

The aim is of course to create robots able to navigate the apps as a human would do.

Comment: Voting to close as needing more focus. Questions are expected to focus on a solvable technical problem, along with your own previous attempts to rectify. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I added my previous attempts regarding browsers, and this problem is absolutely solvable, and well defined.

Comment: @gpier no it's not. Neither well defined nor solvable, precisely because it's not well defined. "The way BluePrims does" doesn't say anything - there were a *lot* of macro recorders in the last 30 years. Besides, applications built with automation in mind (COM automation specifically) *don't need this at all*. YOu don't send clicks to Word, you use COM and Word Interop to talk to it.

Comment: @gpier In the mid-90s macro recorders (and test automation tools in general) people used windows hooks to intercept mouse and keyboard events, or capture windows messages. In the '00s Active Accessibility was introduced, and macro recorders started using it instead, to get access to the window elements directly, the same way accessibility tools do. Browser and Flash broke this because they didn't offer any information, but that changed little by little (except for Flash).

Comment: If you really want to inspect the UI, there are many developer tools that do that and some are part of the Windows SDK, including Spy and now, [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019)

Comment: "The way Blueprism does" says enough for people who know Blueprism, and who approach this question with a constructive attitude. It means that the solution should be able to automate any Windows-based process, and not just those where we can use RDCOM with. Whether this question is well defined is a matter of opinions, and it was certainly useful for me and well defined enough for others. I am obviously not an expert, and neither should I need to be in order to post a question about a certain topic.

Comment: I am not after how people used to do it in the 90's, although I'm grateful for contributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using selenium for web-browsers

There is also some projects for windows based applications working with a Windows Driver.

Take a look to the project on github, it may be what you are looking for.

https://github.com/2gis/Winium

https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver

Comment: pages are not found... can you recheck the links?

Comment: @gpier links fixed, sorry for that

Comment: Many Thanks Jonx, very useful. Could you please share a good tutorial with Python if you have one, using winappdriver?

Comment: @gpier I got this introduction to the winAppDriver on C# but you can get an idea of how it works and then made it work on Python. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EW6lYxVO2ow

Comment: @gpier found a Python sample so you can get an idea https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/Python

Answer (score 2):

Autoit: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

It also comes with an identify mode for application elements and is has a big community

Answer (score 0):

There is a free version of Blue Prism now :) Also Blue Prism uses win32, active accessibility and UI Automation which is a newer for of the older active accessibility.

To do this yourself without looking into Blue Prism you would need to know how to use UIA with C#/VB.new or C++. There are libraries however given that Blue Prism now has a free version I would recommend using that.  Anything specific can be developed withing a code stage within Blue Prism.

Comment: Blue Prism doesn't offer something unique - those features are available since the 1990s, through API calls and SDK tools.